# MSSQL - Invalid object name when attempting an update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL that I can query easily when running `SELECT * FROM Scheme.Table1`

There are no Intellisense errors and I can see the table in the list of tables under the database

If I attempt to run an `UPDATE` against the table, I get the error

```
Msg 208 Invalid object name 'Table1'
```

Updates against other tabes within the same scheme all work fine

What could be causing this error? Is the wording misleading and it is really something else?

EDIT: update statement is...

```
UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE1 SET SCH1 = 'DB', SCH2 = '1' WHERE MEMBERNO = 123999
```

All fields are correct and exist on the table

Comment: Are you using the correct database? I know its a silly question

Comment: Not a silly question at all! I have a USE statement on the line prior and I can confirm I'm using the correct database

Comment: Post your update statement

Comment: Any triggers defined on the table?

Comment: Edited original post to include

Comment: Is it `scheme` or `schema`

Comment: Schema! Sorry, auto bloody correct on my Mac!

Comment: Just spotted that @artm

Comment: Why dont you try UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE1 SET SCH1 = 'DB', SCH2 = '1' WHERE SCHEMA.MEMBERNO = 123999? @Mike

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments, it was a trigger on the table that was referencing itself without the `SCHEMA` (I was logged in using Windows Authentication)